# Help with proving an equality

Tags: analysis

So i am having problems proving an equality.
So here is the whole problem:
Let $0<a<b$ and $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b) $ while  $ a^2 f(b)=b^2f(a)$

So i have to prove that:
 $ \exists  c \in (a,b)$ such that $f'(c)= \frac{2f(c)}{c}$

So i have basic idea that i will have to use mean value theorem or possibly even Rolle's but i am stuck at using that.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rearrange $a^2f(b)=b^2f(a)$ to become $g(a)=g(b)$

Comment: So then Rolle's theorem will be aplicable?

Comment: Can you maybe post a little detailed hint?